# How to retrieve column names from a excel sheet?

Tags: linq, excel, epplus, linq-to-excel, vba

Using `EPPlus` I'm writing data to multiple sheets. If a sheet is not created I'm adding a sheet else I'm retrieving the used rows and adding data from that row and saving it

```
 FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo("Excel.xlsx");
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
  var ws = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == language.Culture);
  if (ws == null)
  {
     worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(language.Culture);
     //writing data
  }
  else
  {
    worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[language.Culture];
    colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
    rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
    //write data
   }
   worksheet.Cells[worksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
   xlPackage.Save();
```

And it is working great.

Now I want to retrieve the column names of each sheet in the excel using `LinqToExcel` and this is my code

```
  string sheetName = language.Culture;
  var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(excelPath);
  IQueryable<Row> excelSheetValues = from workingSheet in            excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName) select workingSheet;
  string[] headerRow = excelFile.GetColumnNames(sheetName).ToArray();
```

At header row it is throwing me an exception

```
An OleDbException exception was caught
External table is not in the expected format.
```

But I don't want to use Oledb and want to work with Linq To Excel.

> Note: When I'm working with single sheet rather than multiple sheets
>   it is working fine and retrieving all columns. Where am I going wrong.

Comment: What happens if you open and save the worksheet in excel after you exported from epplus but before you open with linq2excel?  It could be be epp just generates the raw xml but the sheets are not really generated until excel processes everything.

Comment: What should I do to get all the column names @Ernie

Comment: Does that solve the problem?  Be good to know either way.  If it does, there may not a practical solutions.  Could you use EPPlus to reopen the excel file instead of Ole?

Comment: Actually the problem arises because the columns are not fitted properly, if arranged the column width manually it is working good,I want to know how to do it programatically. I have tried `worksheet.Cells[worksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();` @Ernie

Answer (score 0):

(Based on OP's Comments)

The `AutoFitColumn` function has always been a little touchy.  The important thing to remember is to call it AFTER you load the cell data.

But if you want a use a minimum width (when columns are very narrow and you want to use a minimum) I find EPP to be unreliable.  It seems to always use `DefualtColWidth` of the worksheet even if you pass in a `minimumWidth` to one of the function overloads.

Here is how I get around it:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Autofit_Column_Range_Test()
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31165959/how-to-retrieve-column-names-from-a-excel-sheet

    //Throw in some data
    var datatable = new DataTable("tblData");
    datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Nar", typeof(int))); //This would not be autofitted without the workaround since the default width of a new ws, usually 8.43
    datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Wide Column", typeof(int)));
    datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Really Wide Column", typeof(int)));

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var row = datatable.NewRow();
        row[0] = i;
        row[1] = i * 10;
        row[2] = i * 100;
        datatable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    var existingFile2 = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\temp.xlsx");
    if (existingFile2.Exists)
        existingFile2.Delete();

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile2))
    {
        //Add the data
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        ws.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true);

        //Keep track of the original default of 8.43 (excel default unless the user has changed it in their local Excel install)
        var orginaldefault = ws.DefaultColWidth;
        ws.DefaultColWidth = 15;

        //Even if you pass in a miniumWidth as the first parameter like '.AutoFitColumns(15)' EPPlus usually ignores it and goes with DefaultColWidth
        ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

        //Set it back to what it was so it respects the user's local setting
        ws.DefaultColWidth = orginaldefault;

        package.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey,sorry for the late reply! If I do as u mentioned it is throwing me an exception @Ernie

Comment: @Ajay what is the exception and which line?  Best if you can Paste all of the code by editing your question above.

Comment: I meant to say the same exception arises when reading the values, if I even do this @Ernie

Comment: @AjayA if you are trying to read the EPPlus generated file using Linq2Excel I doubt it will work.  Since EPPlus does not generate a fully executed XLSX (just the raw xml for that excel needs to complete) Linq2Excel must not be able to read it.  Best if you can do all of your manipulation in one technology or the other.

Comment: I have to do some manipulations. which I think Linq2Excel is a best approach for it @Ernie