# How to fit the columns in an excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm writing a list to an excel sheet generated using `EPPlus` with `.xlsx` extension. Then using `worksheet.Cells[worksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();` method I tried to fit the columns.

This is how I write data

```
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
      {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        var ws = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == language.Culture);
        if (ws == null)
         {
          int i = 1, j = 0;
           worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(language.Culture);
           foreach (ExcelFields fieldValues in UnmatchedFieldList)
           {
                 //code
            }
           else
             {
                int i = 0;
                worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[language.Culture];
                colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                 rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                 foreach (ExcelFields fieldValues in UnmatchedFieldList)
                 {
                       worksheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, count + 1].Value = itemName;
                  }
                 worksheet.Cells[worksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
                 xlPackage.Save();
             }
```

I read data as

```
            string sheetName = language.Culture;
            var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(excelPath);
            IQueryable<Row> excelSheetValues = from workingSheet in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName) select workingSheet;
            string[] headerRow = excelFile.GetColumnNames(sheetName).ToArray();
```

> At headerRow it is throwing the below error

When I'm trying to read the data from excel it is throwing an exception

> External table is not in the expected format

I found out,this is due to the columns are not formatted(width) correctly. When I manually set the columns width by double clicking the cell and run the code it is working fine

So I want to achieve this using code

Comment: Could you post all of your code that generates the file and then reads it?

Comment: Checkout my updated question @Ernie

Comment: It seems you are tying to write data with EPPlus and read it with Linq2Excel?  Very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31165959/how-to-retrieve-column-names-from-a-excel-sheet.  The problem is EPPlus does not generate a fully formatted excel file - it creates the raw basic XML inside a renamed zip file (xlsx is just a zip file).  Then when you open in excel it finishes it up.  I suspect L2E is expecting it fully formatted  You best bet is to do everything in EPPlus.  What do you need L2E for that you cannot do in EPPlus?

Comment: Can't we read the data using Linq2Excel? When I have tried the above answer it is throwing me an error @Ernie

Comment: It would appear as though you cannot since no one else has chimed in.  Like I asked before, what are you trying to do in L2E that you cant with EPPlus?  If you have to have L2E then EPPlus may not be the best option. @D Rao

Comment: Actually I'm retrieving all the row values and looping through each row and retrieving each cell value. I have a column "ITEMID", if that is null I have to do something else @Ernie

Answer (score 0):

External table is not in the expected format exception is occurred because of exception of connection string so there fore check your connection string with following sample

```
public static string docPath= @"C:\sourcefolder\myfile.xlsx";
public static string ConnectionString= "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + docPath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
```

or if you use LinqToExcel then check whether you have set setting the DatabaseEngine property like as follows

```
public string docPath= @"C:\sourcefolder\myfile.xlsx";
var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(docPath);
excelFile.DatabaseEngine = DatabaseEngine.Ace;
```

Comment: I'm doing it using LinqToExcel and dont want to use connection strings and it is working fine when the cells are formatted properly @Saveendra Sri

Comment: Check weather database DatabaseEngine property. Look edited answer.

Comment: `string sheetName = language.Culture;
 var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(excelPath);
 IQueryable<Row> excelSheetValues = from workingSheet in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName) select workingSheet;`  This is what I'm doing to retrieve data @ Saveendra Sri Ekanayake

Comment: Add DatabaseEngine like this (excelFile.DatabaseEngine = DatabaseEngine.Ace;)

Comment: Yeah I have tried it, even this didn't resolve the problem